# Decode value from mongodb cursor which is of interface type

Tags: mongodb, go

I am writing an abstraction over the official mongo driver which consists of a struct containing a pointer to the collection needed and CRUD methods on it. In order to be able to work with multiple types(all of which have bson adnotations) I use an interface called Storable, but I don't see a way in which I could decode the field without knowing the type exactly. Code snippet:

```golang
func (c *Collection) GetAll() ([]models.Storable, error) {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    cursor, err := c.coll.Find(ctx, bson.M{})
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    var result []models.Storable

    for cursor.Next(ctx) {
        var doc models.Storable
        err = cursor.Decode(&doc)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        result = append(result, doc)
    }
    return result, nil
}
```

type example:

```golang
type User struct {
    ID        primitive.ObjectID `json:"id" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    FirstName string             `json:"firstName" bson:"firstName"`
    LastName  string             `json:"lastName" bson:"lastName"`
    Email     string             `json:"email" bson:"email"`
    Password  string             `json:"password" bson:"password"`
}
```

Comment: You can't. Somewhere, something, must choose the correct concrete type to be initialized and passed in as the `Storable`. The usual approach seems to be to have a registry (map) of initializers that, based on some key (plain string for example), initialize the correct concrete type e.g. `User`.

Comment: *"but I don't see a way in which I could decode the field without knowing the type exactly."* -- You *must* know the type, at some point, how else are you allocating the `c.coll` field? How else is the code snippet supposed to query the correct collection?

Comment: Thanks man, you are great!

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass in the correct type to decode to somehow. To be able to pass in different types you could use the empty `interface{}`. However if you pass in the entire slice (e.g. []User) into `interface{}` you cannot append to it any more without complex usage of reflection.

### Using a function to create a new row

As @mkopriva mentioned in the comments, we could pass a function creating a new row to it (or pass it to the collection on initialisation):

```golang
func (c *Collection) GetAll(newRow func() models.Storable) ([]models.Storable, error) {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    cursor, err := c.coll.Find(ctx, bson.M{})
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    var result []models.Storable

    for cursor.Next(ctx) {
        nRow := newRow()

        err = cursor.Decode(nRow)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        result = append(result, nRow.(models.Storable))
    }
    return result, nil
}
```

You would then call with a function returning the correct type (must be a pointer):

```golang
rows, err := c.GetAll(func() models.Storable {
    return new(User)
})
```

Here my reference implementation using json decoding to test this: [Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/U0XhrJPtA7-)

### Using reflection to create a new row

You could pass in the variable type for a single row:

```golang
func (c *Collection) GetAll(row models.Storable) ([]models.Storable, error) {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    cursor, err := c.coll.Find(ctx, bson.M{})
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    var result []models.Storable

    for cursor.Next(ctx) {
        nRow := reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(p)).Interface()

        err = cursor.Decode(nRow)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        result = append(result, nRow.(models.Storable))
    }
    return result, nil
}
```

You would then call this with the correct type:

```golang
var user User
rows, err := c.GetAll(user)
```

Note that I don't use a pointer type here! The pointer is taken via reflection in the function.

Here my reference implementation using json decoding to test this: [Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/FFyISO7UhAI)

---

The downside of the "one function for all" is that you now have a slice of `models.Storable` with different data inside and you have to use a type switch or type assertion to work with the data.

For this reason I don't use generic functions for database calls but create a new function for every call I need: e.g. GetAllUsers, GetUserByID, GetAllContacts, etc.

Note: this is one of the things I will rethink when generics get added to Go.

Comment: Curious, have you tested the code in your answer? Does `cursor.Decode` know how to decode into a pointer-to-interface argument? I'm pretty sure `json.Unmarshal` doesn't -- it does but the result ain't the concrete type -- and mongo I don't use which is why I'm asking.

Comment: I assumed that `models.Storable` is just an `interface`. If it isn't, then `row` could be changed to be `interface{}` and incorporated into a new variable of type `models.Storable` before being appended to `result`.

Comment: Also, I'm passing in a concrete type.

Comment: `models.Storable` *is* and interface, and nothing in my previous comment says it isn't.

Comment: I see what you mean

Comment: Got it to work, but not without using reflection to create a new variable for every row. Otherwise all rows would contain the data of the last row.

Comment: Note that there's no need to resort to reflection, also there's no need to require the caller to decide "twice" what concrete type they want (1. using the correct collection, 2. passing the correct type). The custom `Collection` could very easily have a `init func() models.Storable` field which could be set at the same time as the `coll` field is set, the `init` field would be set to a function that initializes the concrete type, e.g. `func() models.Storable { return new(User) }`, then, inside the loop, all you need to do is `v := c.init()` and `if err := cursor.Decode(v); err != nil { ...`

Comment: #mkopriva: thx! I added an example of that to my answer.